# how to change background color of unordered list that includes the bullet

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to color the background of an unordered list in such a way that the bullet also has that background color. Right now, the text has the background color, but the bullet seems to float to its left. I don't want to specify `list-style-position: inside;` because I want the text to line up to the right of the bullet. Here is my code:

```css
ul {
  /*list-style-position: outside;*/
  list-style-type: square;
}

ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.gray-bg {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 1</p>
  </li>
  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 2</p>
  </li>
  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 3</p>
  </li>
  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 4</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `list-style-position:inside` have you tried that ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus " I don't want to specify list-style-position: inside; "

Comment: okay, so is the background a plain color ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus: I'm not sure what a plain color is, but the color is in the question: #F5F5F5

Comment: okay, so my answer should do the trick ;)  with plain color i meant  no gradient / no image

Comment: beside, list-style-position:inside + p {display:inline-block} works too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the bg is a plain background-color, then box-shadow can do the trick.

```css
ul { 
  list-style-type: square;
}

ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow:  -2em 0 #f5f5f5
}

.gray-bg {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 1</p>
  </li>
  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 2</p>
  </li>
  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 3</p>
  </li>
  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 4</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

if you need a border, filter could help

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: square;
}

ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: -2em 0 #f5f5f5;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 0) drop-shadow(-2px 0) drop-shadow( 0 2px) drop-shadow(0 -2px)
}

.gray-bg {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 1</p>
  </li>
  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 2</p>
  </li>
  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 3</p>
  </li>
  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 4</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `::before` selector, which will position our "fake" bullet on top of the background. Also, if you then want to get rid of the gap to the left, you can add `margin: 0; padding: 0;` to your `ul` element.

```css
ul {
  /*list-style-position: outside;*/
  list-style-type: square;
}

ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.gray-bg {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
.gray-bg p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.gray-bg::before {
  content: "\2BC0";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 1</p>
  </li>

  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 2</p>
  </li>

  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 3</p>
  </li>

  <li class="gray-bg">
    <p>Line 4</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This was an interesting approach, but the bullet was set above the the text. Thank you, though!

Comment: Yes, that is an issue, you can fix it by adding `z-index: 2` to the li